# Execution of two functions parallel

Tags: python, python-multithreading

How is it possible to execute two functions with difference of every 5 seconds of time interval till the timer stops using threading in Python.

e.g:

```
def first_func():
    print("First function")

def second_func():
    print("Second function")

Result should be like this:
-------------------------------
First Function     At starts
Second Function    5 Seconds
First Function     10 Seconds
Second Function    15 Seconds
First Function     20 Seconds
Second Function    25 Seconds
First Function     30 Seconds

And so on.
```

Comment: Read up on the threading module, there are plenty of examples and tutorials out there.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use multiprocessing

```
def you_function1(*args, **kwargs):
    pass

def you_function2(*args, **kwargs):
    pass

from multiprocessing import Process

first_process = Process(target=you_function1)

second_process = Process(target=you_function2)

first_process.start()

second_process.start()

first_process.join()
second_process.join()
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html

Comment: I know about threads, but if he would like to faster work - it necessary processing instead threading and remember about GIL(((

Comment: `multiprocessing` can be horribly inefficient or unworkable, depending on what the OP wants to do. For instance, if these threads are monitoring an object in the process space, then child processes wouldn't even work. Sleeping for 5 seconds means the GIL isn't an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Threading is pretty straightforward for this:

```
import threading
import time

def first_func():
    while True:
        print("First function",time.time()-start)
        time.sleep(10)

def second_func():
    time.sleep(5)
    while True:
        print("Second function",time.time()-start)
        time.sleep(10)

start = time.time()
t1 = threading.Thread(target=first_func)
t1.start()
t2 = threading.Thread(target=second_func)
t2.start()
```

Output:

```
First function 0.0
Second function 5.008664846420288
First function 10.002728939056396
Second function 15.010392904281616
First function 20.018056869506836
Second function 25.02572202682495
```